# Adding a scale using SDK GXP OpenGeo Suite

Tags: boundless-suite, scale, sdk

Followed the tutorial using the OpenGeo suite SDK, and looking at adding a scale to my maps however the tutorial doesn't cover adding widgets only plugins. So I am not sure about how I would add http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/lib/widgets/ScaleOverlay.html wherever I place it fr example the tools section I seem to just get a white screen, which tells me something is wrong.

I believe I should call it using

`* @require widgets/ScaleOverlay.js`

and then as with plugins something like (below) in the tools part of app.js

```
 {
ptype: "gxp_ScaleOverlay",
 actionTarget: "map.tbar"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the scale overlay as item to your map configuration in `app.js`, e.g.

```
// map and layers
map: {
    id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above
    title: "Map",
    items: [{
        xtype: "gxp_scaleoverlay"
    }],
    /* ... */
}
```